Web Scraping a Javascript Login Form
I am new to this web scraping but been searching everywhere and cannot find how to solve this problem that i'm having of performing a post Request to a form and get suceesfull login. from what i understand the form uses javascript to generate some values to send to the server for aproval. But it also uses button clicking to fill those same variables (EVENTTARGET and EVENTARGUMENT) ?
Could anyone who have time to take a look at the form code shine a light, or how to proceed. Thanks.
<form method="post" action="./" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



As an alternative to reverse-engineering complex interactions, you might try using a "headless browser" tool, such as Selenium, which would process JavaScript using standard browser functionality.  That way you'd be writing code to interact with the live page, rather than trying to replicate each individual HTTP request made by that page.
